# Sharepoint Timerjob Run by which account?

Tags: sharepoint-server, timer-jobs

In my sharepoint site i have Farm account is different user and application pool is different user.When the timer job runs it will take which account? Farm account or application pool account.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205943/what-user-context-do-sharepoint-timer-jobs-run-under

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timer job by default run under the FArmAdmin account, unless some body change it.

It is not recommend to change timer services account, it should be farm admin all the time.

Farm admin also run the central admin app pool.

Comment: hi waqas in my case execute method i was accessing  network folder.So the folder should be accessible to farm account ?

Comment: correct, are you doing any custom coding?

Comment: yes waqas  farm account dont have access to that folder but apppool account have access to that folder but i got  error access denied to that path.

Comment: give the farm account permission over there and test it

Comment: this one i need to do it in client system Waqas they ionly give permission to that account so i need to ask them.yestreday i thought apppool account so i ask them to give permission for apppool account.But i got access denied error.Just conform me Waqas farm account have access to that folder i won't get this error?

Comment: so we dont know about your account but i can tell you this...Custom code access the location under the App pool account of web application( under which you solution is being run) or Run under the farm admin Account. quick test, as you gave permission to App pool but still get access denied, now give to farm admin and test it.  You can also check the logs or enable log in your code to check which account get the access denied

Comment: another recommendation, open a new thread with your code so developer can help u

Comment: Hi Waqas they gave permission to farm account now it was working thank you so much.

Comment: Great, if my reply works then please mark it answer and upvote so that community get benefit

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE hope to be fine, although you saw the user set my answer as answer but you told him to set your answer as answer !!  should I know why ?!!!!!!! , although your answer is the same of my answer and you answered this after I have answered !! if you need more reputation no proplem , but  you saw the user set my answer , so i think no need to tell him that where you know it will remove it from me !!

Answer (score 0):

It's the User account that runs the `SharePoint Timer Services` in Services List that should be the SharePoint farm account.

[image]

Comment: Sharepoint timer service LogonAs which name is there based on that timerjob will be  run ?

Comment: Execute method i was accessing network shared folder Actually i give permission to that folder who is application pool user.I got access denied error.So if i give farm account user permission to that folder i able to access ?

Comment: the farm account but i don't include it it in image for my privacy

Comment: in your case, what's the app pool account  ?

Comment: Farm admin is servicefarm and app pool is serviceapppool

Comment: any way it should be accessible  if it have access permission

Comment: The Folder having permission for serviceapppool account but i got error access denied

Comment: what about farm account ! is it has access permission ?

Comment: No farm account dont have access to that folder

Comment: Try to provide it access on the folder , and tell me the result !

Comment: Are you sure if i gave access to the farm account it will work.Because i need to ask our client.

Comment: based on your scenario it should work, but don't forget I only have an overview about your situation , meanwhile I suggest to try this first in your side before ask your client !

Comment: HI Qassas Apppool and farm admin dont have permission  but in client system if i give the c dive path it will work.Only problem with network drive folders.

Comment: Hi Qassas they gave permission to farm account now it was working thank you so much.

Comment: Great , i noted that you have set my answer as answer and then remove it , should you set my answer as answer if it helped you :)